# When storing List of Enums in MongoEngine, enums aren't returned when reading the from the database

Tags: python, mongoengine

When using a ListField of EnumField, the data in the objects returned from MongoEngne is not converted back to Enums. For example:

```
class DaysOfTheWeek(Enum):
   Mon = 1
   Tue = 2
   # etc ... 

class C(db.Document):
    days = db.ListField(db.EnumField(DaysOfTheWeek))

c1 = C(days=[DaysOfTheWeek.Mon])
assert c1.days ==  [DaysOfTheWeek.Mon]   # OK 
c1.save()
c2 = C.objects.first()
assert c2.days == [1]                    # OK 
assert c2.days == [DaysOfTheWeek.Mon]    # Fails
```

Is this expected behaviour? Am I using MongoEngine incorrectly?

I am using MongoEngine 0.22.1.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Just ran across the same thing.

Comment: No, I gave up on EnumFields, seem too buggy and under documented to use

Comment: There is a [merge request](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/pull/2531) that supposedly fixes this, but it is stuck on approval...

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
assert c2.days == [DaysOfTheWeek.Mon]
```

with:

```
assert c2.days == [DaysOfTheWeek.Mon.value]
```

Comment: Why would it help. Could you elaborate a bit?